# Calculator button (Android) - Distinguishing between normal click and longClick (for sine and arc sine functions)

Tags: android, calculator, trigonometry

Below I've listed two functions. I have a button for "sine" function - which works perfectly and on LongClick I want to add the sine inverse function or arc sine.

***NOTE : The difference between the two functions below is just the one line where I assign afterSin variable, in one I use Math.sin in the other - Math.asin, that's it no more difference.

The problem is , normal click or long Click , I'm getting the "Sine" function only, even though I've coded asin function, I don't why but it seems to ignore it and gives the normal click function. (Again, on longClicking it doesn't give the arc sine function as I want it to, but simply gives the normal function "sine" , that is the same as normal OnClick function.)

Here's the normal OnClick :

```
public void onClickListener_sin(View v) {
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    EditTextMsg = editText.getText().toString();
    doubleEditTextMsg = Double.parseDouble(EditTextMsg);// degree

    toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg = Math.toRadians(doubleEditTextMsg);

    afterSin = Math.sin(toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg);
```

////////Only different line is the above one (Sin, here and ASin below )
        editText.setText(afterSin.toString());

```
    EditTextMsg = editText.getText().toString();
    result = Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    result_mul = Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    result_div = Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    sum = "";

}
```

AND
Here's the LongClick function (I want it to give asin, but it ignores the function and continues with the normal(above function and gives me "Sine" )

```
  button_sin.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            vibrator.vibrate(30);

            EditTextMsg = editText.getText().toString();
            doubleEditTextMsg = Double.parseDouble(EditTextMsg);// degree

            toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg = Math.toRadians(doubleEditTextMsg);


            afterSin = Math.asin(toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg);
            ///////////////The above line is the only difference between this and the above    ///////////function
            editText.setText(afterSin.toString());

            EditTextMsg = editText.getText().toString();
            result = Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

            result_mul = Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

            result_div = Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

            sum = "";

            return true;
                }
            });
```

I'm showing the results and inputs in a EditText box ...
(The result, result_mul, sum variables should not be relevant to this question, I copied them anyways because they are used for the respective functions in my calculators specific code... It shouldn't be related to the current problem)

So, Can you spot anything wrong ?
(It ignores the onLongClick....and simply carries out the normal Onclick function (The same function whether the click is normal or long)

Thank you.

Comment: I think You should set this button onClickListenr like You did it with onLongClickListener. like button_sin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()){});

Comment: But I'm linking the one I have Directly... I'll try this anyways, i dont care how it works... be right back ..

Answer (score 0):

It may help to enable the button's long-clickable attribute

```
button_sin.setLongClickable(true); // CODE
```

OR

```
android:longClickable="true" // XML
```

Then as pointed out by @Opiatefuchs, you should really be calling `.setOnLongClickListener()` in the same way as you provide the `.setOnClickListener()` for neatness' sake.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yup, That's not the problem.. turns out , I hadn't done this eariler, but still the program shows no difference whatsover... Actually If you see my function, the last line "return true" is actually doing just this ...(I think ) , its setting the Listener to "On" ... The problem is in the code, idk why it is not giving me Asine, it just gives "Sine" on both normal and longClicks ...

Comment: Hmmmm, righto. Have you tried putting a toast in to debug which function is being called?